# How to stop BeautifulSoup from prepending namespaces to my XML tags?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, svg, beautifulsoup

This is the XML code of my Scalable Vector Graphics(SVG) image,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg height="297mm" id="svg8" inkscape:version="1.0.1 (3bc2e813f5, 2020-09-07)" sodipodi:docname="whatever.svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 210 297" width="210mm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs id="defs2"/>
 <sodipodi:namedview bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity="1.0" id="base" inkscape:current-layer="layer1" inkscape:cx="205.42115" inkscape:cy="886.52685" inkscape:document-rotation="0" inkscape:document-units="mm" inkscape:pageopacity="0.0" inkscape:pageshadow="2" inkscape:window-height="705" inkscape:window-maximized="1" inkscape:window-width="1366" inkscape:window-x="0" inkscape:window-y="27" inkscape:zoom="0.98994949" pagecolor="#ffffff" showgrid="false"/>
 <metadata id="metadata5">
  <rdf:RDF>
   <cc:Work rdf:about="">
    <dc:format>
     image/svg+xml
    </dc:format>
    <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
    <dc:title/>
   </cc:Work>
  </rdf:RDF>
 </metadata>
 <g id="layer1" inkscape:groupmode="layer" inkscape:label="Layer 1">
  <path d="m 107.80657,119.33592 c -44.409528,3.08098 -44.322229,71.4721 -5.28416,79.19191" id="path8" style="fill:none;stroke:#00ff00;stroke-width:5;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

When I parse it using `bs4.BeautifulSoup()`,

```py
>>>print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(xml_code, 'xml').prettify())
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg:svg height="297mm" id="svg8" inkscape:version="1.0.1 (3bc2e813f5, 2020-09-07)" sodipodi:docname="whatever.svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 210 297" width="210mm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<svg:defs id="defs2"/>
<sodipodi:namedview bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity="1.0" id="base" inkscape:current-layer="layer1" inkscape:cx="205.42115" inkscape:cy="886.52685" inkscape:document-rotation="0" inkscape:document-units="mm" inkscape:pageopacity="0.0" inkscape:pageshadow="2" inkscape:window-height="705" inkscape:window-maximized="1" inkscape:window-width="1366" inkscape:window-x="0" inkscape:window-y="27" inkscape:zoom="0.98994949" pagecolor="#ffffff" showgrid="false"/>
<svg:metadata id="metadata5">
<rdf:RDF>
<cc:Work rdf:about="">
<dc:format>
     image/svg+xml
    </dc:format>
<dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
<dc:title/>
</cc:Work>
</rdf:RDF>
</svg:metadata>
<svg:g id="layer1" inkscape:groupmode="layer" inkscape:label="Layer 1">
<svg:path d="m 107.80657,119.33592 c -44.409528,3.08098 -44.322229,71.4721 -5.28416,79.19191" id="path8" style="fill:none;stroke:#00ff00;stroke-width:5;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"/>
</svg:g>
</svg:svg>
```

`BeautifulSoup` prepends `svg` namespace to all the tags without namespace. Is there a way to prevent `BeautifulSoup` from doing it?